# Android: Can't update release version as gson was not added exception to pro guard

Tags: android, sqlite, gson, obfuscation, minify

The situation:

1. Objects (.com.package.model) are stored inside a SQLite Database as Gson strings
2. currently no proguard exceptions were added
3. app is released on the play store
4. after updating the release, app crashes with "Expected begin array but found String" error
5. disabling proguard or adding the exceptions to both releases lets the error disappear
   As the app is already released, does anyone know how I can map the old apk to the new one?
   I am willing to pay you a coffee ;)

Used exceptions:

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

Comment: So the problem is that you (unfortunately) have JSON with obfuscated property names in your database and want to support reading it in a backward compatible way?

Comment: Exactly on point. Do you have an idea what to do? My only idea is to delete the database. But this would probably upset many users.

Comment: You could probably based on the mapping file generated by ProGuard manually annotate the fields of your class with `@SerializedName` and use [`alternate`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html#alternate()) to specify the obfuscated field names. Alternatively you could add your own annotation and specify a custom [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) which reads them. There might be more solutions to this.

Comment: Awesome this worked. If you want you can answer my questions so I can accept it. The only thing I still don't understand: after adding for example this line: "@SerializedName(value = "roomName", alternate = "b")" the new mapping still says: "java.lang.String roomName -> a" and a new line was added as well "1:1:void <init>():7:7 -> <init>".

Comment: As far as I understand it, ProGuard leaves the annotations unchanged. And Gson prefers `@SerializedName` over obtaining the property name based on the field name (respectively from `FieldNamingStrategy`). Therefore once `@SerializedName` is used, it does not matter that the field names are obfuscated. (I hope that is what you meant.) But you must be careful not to forget `@SerializedName` on one of the fields; otherwise you will run into the same problem again. Not sure why ProGuard added a new line for `<init>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the mapping files generated by ProGuard for your previous release, you could manually annotate the fields of your model classes with Gson's `@SerializedName` and use [`alternate`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html#alternate()) to specify the obfuscated field names. The `alternate` values are only considered during deserialization, and therefore allow you to specify meaningful property names through the `value` of the `@SerializedName` annotations, which will be used for any newly serialized data.